# Adding red color to wrong answer if picked

Tags: javascript

I really can't figure it out, I tried to select the answer with query in js than style it red but it says that the value is undefined...
Also i tried to style with CSS but I don't know how it works combined with bootstrap.

Here is the HTML:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Ninja Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- top section -->
    <div class="intro py-3 bg-white text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-primary display-3 my4">Ninja Quiz</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- result section -->
    <div class="result py-4 d-none bg-light text-center">
        <div class="container lead">
            <p>You are <span class="text-primary display-4 p-3">0%</span>ninja</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- quiz section -->
    <div class="quiz py-4 bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="my-5 text-white">On with the questions...</h2>

            <form class="quiz-form text-light">
                <!-- Question One -->
                <div class="my-5">
                    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">1. How do you give a ninja directions?</p>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label">Show them a map</label> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B">
                        <label class="form-check-label">Don't worry, a ninja will find you</label> 
                    </div>
                </div>


                    <!-- Question Two -->

                    <div class="my-5">
                        <p class="lead font-weight-normal">2. If a ninja has 3 apples, then gives one to Sonic & one to Tales, how many apples the ninja have left?</p>
                        <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label">One apple</label> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="B">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Zero apples because Sonic runs away with Tales!!!</label> 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <!-- Question Three -->
                        
                        <div class="my-5">
                            <p class="lead font-weight-normal">3. How do you know when you've met a ninja?</p>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A" checked>
                                <label class="form-check-label">You'll recognize the outfit</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="B">
                                <label class="form-check-label">You just saw an illusion</label> 
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- Question Four -->

                        <div class="my-5">
                            <p class="lead font-weight-normal">4.What is a ninja's favourite array method?</p>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="A" checked>
                                <label class="form-check-label">forEach()</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="B">
                                <label class="form-check-label">Slice()</label> 
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send Results" class="btn btn-light">
                        </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And JS:

```
const correctAnswers = ['B','B','B','B'];
const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

form.addEventListener ('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    let score = 0;
    const userAnswers = [form.q1.value, form.q2.value, form.q3.value, form.q4.value];

    // check answers
    userAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        if(answer === correctAnswers[index]){
            score+=25;
        } 
        
     
    });

    //show result on page
    scrollTo(0,0);
    result.querySelector('span').textContent = `${score}%`;
    result.classList.remove('d-none');
    
    let output = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        result.querySelector('span').textContent = `${output}%`;
        if(output === score){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }else {
            output++;
        }
    }, 10);

});
```

Sorry if I pasted the code wrongly, I'm a really basic junior dev and that's my first post :(

Thanks in advice for any help that you guys could provide to me.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a more specific question about the problem you're having. It really doesn't involve red text, but some aspect of your code logic.

Comment: Do you want to highlight the wrong checkbox with red color when the user submits his answers?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do here? After the user submits his answers, let him know which answers he has submitted are correct and which ones are wrong?

You can edit the styles of .wrong-answer, these ones are just for illustration purposes.

Click "Send results" and you'll see it.

```js
const correctAnswers = ['B','B','B','B'];
const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

form.addEventListener ('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    let score = 0;
    const userAnswers = [form.q1.value, form.q2.value, form.q3.value, form.q4.value];

    // check answers
    userAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
      const currentSelectedInput =  form[`q${index + 1}`][answer === form[`q${index + 1}`][0].value ? 0 : 1];
      console.log(currentSelectedInput);
        if(answer === correctAnswers[index]){
            score+=25;
        } 
        else {
        currentSelectedInput.parentNode.classList.add('wrong-answer');
        }
     
    });

    //show result on page
    scrollTo(0,0);
    result.querySelector('span').textContent = `${score}%`;
    result.classList.remove('d-none');
    
    let output = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        result.querySelector('span').textContent = `${output}%`;
        if(output === score){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }else {
            output++;
        }
    }, 10);
})
```

```css
.wrong-answer input {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrong-answer label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    
    </style>
    <title>Ninja Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- top section -->
    <div class="intro py-3 bg-white text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-primary display-3 my4">Ninja Quiz</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- result section -->
    <div class="result py-4 d-none bg-light text-center">
        <div class="container lead">
            <p>You are <span class="text-primary display-4 p-3">0%</span>ninja</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- quiz section -->
    <div class="quiz py-4 bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="my-5 text-white">On with the questions...</h2>

            <form class="quiz-form text-light">
                <!-- Question One -->
                <div class="my-5">
                    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">1. How do you give a ninja directions?</p>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label">Show them a map</label> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B">
                        <label class="form-check-label">Don't worry, a ninja will find you</label> 
                    </div>
                </div>


                    <!-- Question Two -->

                    <div class="my-5">
                        <p class="lead font-weight-normal">2. If a ninja has 3 apples, then gives one to Sonic & one to Tales, how many apples the ninja have left?</p>
                        <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label">One apple</label> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="B">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Zero apples because Sonic runs away with Tales!!!</label> 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <!-- Question Three -->
                        
                        <div class="my-5">
                            <p class="lead font-weight-normal">3. How do you know when you've met a ninja?</p>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A" checked>
                                <label class="form-check-label">You'll recognize the outfit</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="B">
                                <label class="form-check-label">You just saw an illusion</label> 
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- Question Four -->

                        <div class="my-5">
                            <p class="lead font-weight-normal">4.What is a ninja's favourite array method?</p>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="A" checked>
                                <label class="form-check-label">forEach()</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
                                <input type="radio" name="q4" value="B">
                                <label class="form-check-label">Slice()</label> 
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send Results" class="btn btn-light">
                        </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I wrong copied the html part, don't know what happened

Comment: The only thing i modified was the color of the wrong-answer label to green and deleted the text decoration, in this way now the correct answer is green, before that the right answer was labeled in red line-through but in that way the aswer seems wrong. it is possible to add the red text on the wrong one now, othr the green text i just modified? thank you so much.

Comment: Also I noticed that if I change the right answer in the array from B to A the code part you added still act like the correct answer is B

Comment: I've fixed the code, it really highlights the wrong answer now. The class .wrong-answer highlights the wrong answer, not the correct one. Is that what you want?